# Create tabs with 2 rows of tabs, 1 content box, javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am wondering if anyone has a solution for what seems like an easy problem.

I am trying to create a tab box that has a row of tabs that run across the top of the content box and another row that runs along the bottom of the content box.

Something like this:

```
  <div id="tabContainer">
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li id="tabHeader_1">Tab 1</li>
        <li id="tabHeader_2">Tab 2</li>
        <li id="tabHeader_3">Tab 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tabscontent">
      <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_1">
        <h2>Page 1</h2>
        <p>Content 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_2">
        <h2>Page 2</h2>
        <p>Content 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_3">
        <h2>Page 3</h2>
        <p>Content 3</p>
      </div>
              <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_4">
        <h2>Page 4</h2>
        <p>Content 4</p>
      </div>
              <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_5">
        <h2>Page 5</h2>
        <p>Content 5</p>
      </div>
              <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_6">
        <h2>Page 6</h2>
        <p>Content 6</p>
      </div>
    </div>
          <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li id="tabHeader_4">Tab 4</li>
        <li id="tabHeader_5">Tab 5</li>
        <li id="tabHeader_6">Tab 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Muchos thank yous to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can not use `id` on a multiple elements, `id`'s are uniqiue. Change your `tabs` `id` to `class`. Second thing: change your li selector's id's like this for easy manipulation.

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/QqJ5X/6/)

**html:**

```
   <ul>
        <li id="header_tabpage_1">Tab 1</li>
        <li id="header_tabpage_2">Tab 2</li>
        <li id="header_tabpage_3">Tab 3</li>
   </ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabpage').hide().first().show();

    $('.tabs ul li').click(function() {
       var target = $(this).attr('id').replace('header_','');
       //this will return like 'tabpage_1'

       $('.tabpage').hide();
       $('#'+ target).fadeIn(500);

       $('.tabs ul li').removeClass('selected');
       $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@barlas already stated that `#tabs` existed twice on the same page: this isn't allowed, use classes.

Here's a fiddle concentrating on the style (CSS) part: **http://jsfiddle.net/XXhSQ/**

Rows of tabs (both on top and bottom) and the content are displayed as `table-row` (and their container is displayed as `table`).
They're still unsemantic div; these `table-things` are only visual display algorithms applying to them and not suddenly tables used as layout (the latter would mean using HTML elements like `table`, `tr` and `td`).

Then `a` elements are added into `.tabs>li` because tabs must be clickable with mouse and focusable with keyboard (and touch, also).
They're displayed as `block` to occupy the whole width of their container, when their container (`li`) are displayed as cells of equal widths.
Finally some backgrounds, borders and different rounded borders both on `tabs-up` and `tabs-down` for demo purposes.

Compatibility is IE8+. A fallback for IE7- would be using `.tabs li { display: inline;zoom:1;}` (that's the equivalent of `display: inline-block` for IE7- because they don't understand either table-things nor inline-block ...)